# Selection of a specific inline style

Tags: jquery

how can I select only the divs with style "right:200px" in jquery?

Example:

```
<div class="test" style="position:absolute; right:200px; top:10px;"><p>Hello</p></div>
<div class="test" style="position:absolute; right:300px; top:20px;"><p>Hello</p></div>
<div class="test" style="position:absolute; right:400px; top:70px;"><p>Hello</p></div>
<div class="test" style="position:absolute; right:200px; top:40px;"><p>Hello</p></div>
<div class="test" style="position:absolute; right:400px; top:100px;"><p>Hello</p></div>
<div class="test" style="position:absolute; right:200px; top:140px;"><p>Hello</p></div>


var div200 = $('.test').css('right');
```

I don't know how to select only the divs with "right:200px".
I'm new to jquery. I tried hard but without any success:

Achim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var div200 = $('.test').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('right') == "200px";
});
```

Comment: That's so much easier than all the string manipulation I was looking at doing...+1, for pure-awesome! :)

Comment: Hi David, this is realy short an readable - thanks for the solution. Well, I have to maniuplate on a given inline style, I know it is better to aviod inline styles with css. But no problem with jquery.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.test').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('right') == "200px";
}).addClass('selected');
```

[**See example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/rp4HM/)

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to select only the divs with "right:200px".

This is probably possible somehow, but it's a bit against how jQuery and CSS are supposed to work. Consider putting the actual position information into classes:

```
div.p1 { position:absolute; right:200px; top:10px; }
div.p2 { position:absolute; right:300px; top:20px; }
....
etc.
```

and having a simplified div structure:

```
<div class="test p1"><p>Hello</p></div> 
<div class="test p2"><p>Hello</p></div>
etc.
```

and then addressing each div using

```
var div1 = $('.test.p1');
var div2 = $('.test.p2');
etc.
```

that also makes you independent from specific numbers like `200px` - the only place where you change it is in the style sheet.